# Server providing old version of a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, server

I have a website under `.htaccess` password. 
And the file `/static/js/main.js` on the server is not the one being served when accessed.

I first thought it was a problem of browser caching, but after I cleared everything it was the same, and it's sure it's not browser cache problem because even :

`wget www.website.com/static/js/main.js` 
downloads the wrong old file.

What can be wrong ? How to solve this?

PS : When I noticed the served file was the wrong old one yesterday I tried removing htaccess to refresh but it was the same and I putted it again. Now, every file on the websites requires a password, except that old `/static/js/main.js`...

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the right path when edited file? looks like you edited the file in another folder

Comment: Yes I am sure, I checked hundreds of time through the FTP.

Comment: Do you have a cache system on your server? Or between you and your server? Like cloudflare?

Comment: I don't think so. It's sure we dont have cloudflare tho. We're using OVH shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you could try this:

First, we use the following rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

Now, we write the following PHP function:

```
/**
 *  Given a file, i.e. /css/base.css, replaces it with a string containing the
 *  file's mtime, i.e. /css/base.1221534296.css.
 *  
 *  @param $file  The file to be loaded.  Must be an absolute path (i.e.
 *                starting with slash).
 */
function auto_version($file)
{
  if(strpos($file, '/') !== 0 || !file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file))
    return $file;

  $mtime = filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file);
  return preg_replace('{\\.([^./]+)$}', ".$mtime.\$1", $file);
}
```

Now, wherever you include your CSS, change it from this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" type="text/css" />
```

To this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo auto_version('/css/base.css'); ?>" type="text/css" />
```

This way, you never have to modify the link tag again, and the user will always see the latest CSS. The browser will be able to cache the CSS file, but when you make any changes to your CSS the browser will see this as a new URL, so it won't use the cached copy.

This can also work with images, favicons, and JavaScript. Basically anything that is not dynamically generated.

Comment: Yes this would resolve the problem. The cache for the file was 1 year, updated htaccess now to 0 second, however, I guess the rooter serving the file still thinks it has to serve main.js for 1 year.
How could we reset the rooter / dns's cached file they serve when requested "main.js" ?

Comment: Please read this article http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/cache/ It may help you,